# Primefaces (TabView): Propriedades nulas ao salvar

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, cdi

Estou utilizando uma TabView com duas abas e cada aba com um arquivo externo com campos. Ao clicar no botão "Salvar" os atributos estão vindo como nulos.
Segue o código:

ClientesCadastrados.xhtml:

```
...
<h:form id="frm-cadastro-cliente-dialog">
    <p:dialog header="Cadastrar Cliente" widgetVar="cadastroClienteDialog">
        <p:tabView>
            <p:tab title="Dados Pessoais">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/cliente/ClientePartialDadosPessoais.xhtml" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>

            <p:tab title="Endereço">
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/cliente/ClientePartialEndereco.xhtml" />
                </h:panelGrid>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>

        <p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{clienteBean.salvar}"/>
    </p:dialog>    
</h:form>
...
```

ClientePartialDadosPessoais.xhtml:

```
...
<p:outputLabel value="Nome" for="nome" />
<p:inputText id="nome" required="true" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.nome}" />

<p:outputLabel value="E-mail" for="email" />
<p:inputText id="email" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.email}" />

<!--  outros campos... -->
```

ClientePartialEndereco.xhtml:

```
...
<p:outputLabel value="Logradouro" for="logradouro" />
<p:inputText id="logradouro" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.logradouro}" />

<p:outputLabel value="Complemento" for="complemento" />
<p:inputText id="complemento" value="#{clienteBean.cliente.complemento}" />

<!--  Outros campos... -->
...
```

ClienteBean.java:

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class ClienteBean {

    @Inject
    private Cliente cliente;

    public void salvar() {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + cliente.getNome()); //null
        System.out.println("E-mail: " + cliente.getEmail()); //null
        System.out.println("Logradouro: " + cliente.getLogradouro()); //null
        System.out.println("Complemento: " + cliente.getComplemento()); //null
        ...
    }
}
```

Obs: Estou usando CDI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que faltou processar o formulario.
Experimente no  processar o formulario
Ex

```
<p:commandButton value="Salvar" action="#{clienteBean.salvar}" process="@form"/>
```

Pode tambem ser problema de scope,  tente mudar para @ViewScoped  do javax.faces.view.ViewScoped ao invés de @RequestScoped. E mantenha o process="@form"

Comment: Obrigado Marcelo, mas não foi. Tentei também o update mas também não deu certo.

Comment: Adicionei um complemento na resposta. veja se agora funciona.

Comment: Marcelo quando eu coloquei o ViewScoped do CDI deu erro ao iniciar o Tomcat 8. Não entendi, pois eu configurei o context.xml e o web.xml para isso. Você sabe o que pode ser isso também?

Comment: Veja se o import esta como javax.faces.view.ViewScoped

Comment: Sim, está dessa forma.

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser. Eu utilizo com Wildfly 10.1 não conheco p Tomcat 8

Comment: Valeu Marcelo, o problema era não ter colocado o ViewScoped mesmo. E o erro que estava dando no tomcat ao colocar o ViewScoped era porque eu não estava serializando a classe.